# How to increase width of docfx article page (based-on default theme)?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, docfx

I am using docfx 2.43.3 with own theme (based on `default` theme). This is the result: `http://docs.example.com/`.

In this article page, http://docs.example.com/articles/add_more.html.

How would you increase the width of this page (all page and main block)?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As a possible first step, you could try changing all `container`s to `container-fluid`.

```js
var containers = $(".container");
containers.removeClass("container");
containers.addClass("container-fluid");
```

Comment: @DoNhuVy Don't forget to mark answers as `Accepted`, if they solve the problem.